# How to decrypt video with sample-aes-ctr encryption

Tags: encryption, aes, m3u8

I downloaded my video lecture using ffmpeg. But it was not decrypted as sample aes is not supported by ffmpeg till now. Link to m3u8: https://pw.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/b7826d86-612d-4ef2-b17c-cc4f91d9584c/master.m3u8
Please help me as I need it very much.
I would be using mp4decrypt or any other decrtypter...but how to get keys and other things required for decryption?
**Warning**: I am not involved in any kind of piracy. I am stakeholder of that video and unable to download due to software limitations. It can be watched online but there comes my hardware limitation and hence it lags very much.
Please help me

Comment: Kindly edit your post and add the code you have written so far and struggling with, thanks.

Comment: It is now supported by ffmpeg, but you still need a key.